# How would you go through this combination/ permutation problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A market has 30 different pants and 12 different hats. You want to to get 3 different pants and 2 different hats.

How many ways can you make this purchase?

I assume this is a combination, but stuck in how to go though.

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of ways to choose 3 things out of 30?

Comment: C(30, 3). But what about the others

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the number of ways to pick 3 different items out of 30, find the number of ways to pick 2 different items out of 12, and then multiply both results.

Comment: Is it a combination since order is not restricted, right?

Comment: @jeffmoore, Yes.

Comment: So, how come you multiply both results instead of adding them?

Comment: You multiply when events are dependent.

Comment: You multiply because for each of the $\binom{30}{3}$ ways you can select three pairs of pants, you can choose the two hats in $\binom{12}{2}$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ is the number of ways you can choose $k$ items from a set of $n$ items when order does not matter.

The $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = (n)(n-1)...(n-k+1)$ term is the number of ways you can arrange $k$ items since you first have $n$ choices for the first item,  then $n-1$ choices for the second and so on.

However his is over counting as for each arrangement of $k$ items there are $k!$ ways to rearrange them (eg, k=3, ABC ACB BAC BCA CAB CBA) so we correct this with $\frac{1}{k!}$

In your question the answer is 
${30 \choose 3}{12 \choose 2}$
since you want to choose 3 pants from the 30 available pants and for each of these sets you will then choose 2 hats from the 12 available hats

Comment: Basically I have to multiply both results?

Comment: Yes, there are ${30 \choose 2}$ ways to choose 3 pants and for each of these choices there are ${12 \choose 2}$ ways to choose 2 hats